# Inserting rows to a table from another SELECT - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `CountriesList` with `ID` and `Country` columns.
I have another table called `Entries` which have a column named `Country`.

I would like to `INSERT` all the countries in `Entries` into CountriesList... I am using the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO CountriesList ('Country') 
SELECT DISTINCT ('Country')
FROM  `Entries`
```

However, I get

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

What is wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix up single quotes (`'`) and backticks (`` ` ``).

Backticks are for database and column names.

Single quotes are used for strings.

```
INSERT INTO `CountriesList`
(`Country`) 
SELECT DISTINCT `Country` FROM `Entries`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Insert into entries(country) 

     select distinct(country) from 

    countrylist where country not in

     (select country from entries)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be -

```
INSERT INTO CountriesList
(Country) 
SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM  Entries
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
insert into Entries (country) select country from CountriesList